# I can't find my nautilus settings

Tags: unity, nautilus

My nautilus browser looks like this:

[image]

I can't find the settings anywhere.
I've tried reinstalling nautilus.

Comment: Reinstalling software will never affect your configuration. That is why you can reinstall the operating system without loosing any data or settings as long as you have /home on a separate filesystem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Go to where I added in the arrow. It will show `file`, `edit`, `view`,`history`,`tools`,`help` when you hovern over the black area there.
The `edit` holds `preferences`.